# bit complement operator in euclidean division

Tags: java, c++, c, bit-manipulation

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679146/euclidean-divison-program

did not answer this query.

I learnt that, Given two integers a and b, with b ≠ 0, there exist unique integers q and r such that a = bq + r and 0 ≤ r < |b|, where |b| denotes the absolute value of b - Definition euclidean division

Corresponding program that implements this logic is as shown below:

```
int ifloordiv(int n, int d){

if (n >= 0)
    return n / d;
else
    return ~(~n / d);
}
```

After reading the above code, It look obvious for me to understand if(n>=0){} block code logic that we are doing real division not euclidean.

But, else{(n<0)} code logic using bit complement operator(~) was not looking obvious to me to understand the thinking approach behind usage of ~ operator. Generally we use >> operator when we think of division.

I know that java ~ operator is 1's complement operator on integral types.

My question is:

I would like to understand the thinking approach on, How can i think of using bit complement operator(~) that it helps you to perform euclidean divison when n<0. Because it was not obvious for me to think on using ~ operator. Please help me tune my approach.

Comment: What language is this in? You mention Java but tag C and C++..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~n` is `-n - 1`.

So `~(~n / d)` is `-((-n - 1) / d) - 1`.

For negative values of `n` and positive values of `d`, this turns out to be division that rounds down (division normally rounds towards zero, so up for negative values of `n`). I can't explain why that is.

Comment: If you divide two numbers where one is positive and one is negative, I believe the rounding may be poorly-defined in C90, it may round either up or down. I think such nonsense was fixed in C99, so it might be wise to use a modern C compiler for these kind of things.

Comment: @Lundin The rounding of the division was **implementation-defined** in C90. Basically no hardware platform ever did anything different than what was later standardized in C99. Hence the apparently backwards-incompatible strengthening of the specification in C99, and for the same reason, you are completely safe with a C90 compiler: division is implementation-defined and the C90 compiler implementation will not have defined it differently than what is in C99.

Comment: I am continuing with immibis idea of mathematical relation to my old thread [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679146/euclidean-divison-program)